# pyenchant cirtial enchant_is_all_caps and enchant_is_title_case assertion message

Tags: python, pyenchant

I use pyenchant to auto-correct words, e.g.

```
import enchant
myDic = enchant.Dict('en_EN')
print myDict.check('foo')
```

**Problem**: I get the following error message from enchant, though it does not crash

```
** (process:24563): CRITICAL **: enchant_is_title_case: assertion `word && *word' failed

** (process:24563): CRITICAL **: enchant_is_all_caps: assertion `word && *word' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in a discussion in the [pyenchant GIT repository](https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant/issues/11):

It was an empty line (or something that is interpret as such) in my personal dictionary.
I have mine in `~/.config/enchant/en_EN.dic`

Removing the empty line solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, I was source-diving to find if the PWL file (personal word list) can have comments (it can, line must start with `#`, and it must be in the first column). If you need a line to separate the file logically, just add an empty comment line.